# Infinite loop on a supreme bot

Tags: javascript, automation, bots

I have a problem with some code, I got a function with a loop scanning all  in the source code and redirect to the right link but the redirect is not stopping i really don't know why.

```
function pickColor(){

    chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data){
        var test = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            if (test[i].getAttribute("data-style-name") == color){
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: test[i].href});
                break;
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's your issue, but never use `.length` directly into the comparison. Because it's executed on every iteration. Create a const that stock your length instead

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning color but data

```js
function pickColor() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(color) { // or data, but then use data.color
    var test = document.querySelector('a[data-style-name=' + color + ']');
    if (test) chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: test.href});
  })
}
```

Comment: thx for you help man, its better now but still making an infinite loop

Comment: How are you calling pickColor?